# Array data incorrect on loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a series of variables that are collected in a while next loop.
I wanted to store these in an array so that I can access them later in some javascript, so I set

```
$remainingTime = array();
```

before while (!$listing->EOF) {

After the variables are populated I then added

```
$remainingTime[] = array( $remainingDay, $remainingHour, $remainingMinutes, $remainingSeconds );
```

If I do

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($remainingTime);
echo "</pre>";
```

after the loop is finished I get the following output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 34
        [3] => 1
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 34
        [3] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 12
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 34
        [3] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 12
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 16
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 33
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 14
        [2] => 34
        [3] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 12
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 16
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 33
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 38
        [3] => 17
    )

)
```

So it appears that it is building a new array each time it goes through the loop rather than just adding the next dataset to it.

Where have I gone wrong with building the array?

Comment: show your php code where you placed loop

Answer (score 0):

The assignment syntax you used ($remainingTime[]) pushes the value you assign it as a new element into the array. Try it without using the square brackets.

Comment: Whilst that resolved the issue, it presents another problem because now the array presents as Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 34
    [3] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 33
    [3] => 12
)
) 
so there is nothing there to distinguish which iteration of the array I want to access. By this I mean that each dataset has [0], [1] etc

Comment: I'd need to see the function that populates your arrays for that, and I'm also unsure what you want the end result to be. I'm guessing you want these to be in an associative array, in which case when assigning them values do something like this $remainingDay['someindex'] = 5